# Training a machine learning model using a data expansion generator is interrupted. What could be the cause and how to solve it?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am reading Scholle's book on deep learning using Keras. Got to training a convolutional neural network from scratch on a small dataset(training data: 1000 photos of cats and 1000 photos of dogs, validation data: 500 cat photos and 500 dog photos). When training the machine learning model, a training interruption occurs at step #63.On the google colab site I get the error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure 
that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` 
batches (in this case, 10000 batches). You may need to use the repeat() 
function when building your dataset.

WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure 
that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` 
batches (in this case, 50 batches).
```

All the code was copied from a book. Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

````
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(150,150,3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))#thinning
model.add(layers.Dense(512,activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
             optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=1e-4),
             metrics=['acc'])

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
rescale=1./255,
rotation_range=40,
width_shift_range=0.2,
height_shift_range=0.2,
shear_range=0.2,
zoom_range=0.2,
horizontal_flip=True,)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir,
                                                   target_size=(150,150),
                                                   batch_size=32,
                                                   class_mode='binary')
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(validation_dir,
                                                        target_size=(150,150),
                                                        batch_size=32,
                                                        class_mode='binary')
history = model.fit(train_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch = 100,
                    epochs = 100,
                    validation_data=validation_generator,
                    validation_steps = 50)```
````